# Facebook Cookie

Tags: facebook, authentication, cookies

How can I get the Facebook user id when a user visits my website? I assume I need to read the Facebook cookie. How is that done?

The reason I want to grab the Facebook user id is I can then check my website's database to determine if the user has linked their Facebook account to my website and thus auto log them in.

I am assuming this is the key to how sites like Groupon are doing their auto log on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly read the Facebook cookie, as that would violate various security features of cookies. What you're looking for instead is probably the Facebook login buttons. This should get you started: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Thanks Waynn! Let me ask the question another way. How is Groupon able to log a user onto their site by having the user click the facebook "log on" button? With that method there is no need for the user to once more go through the facebook app authroization process and "allow" the app access to the user's facebook account assuming it was done already. Of course this assumes the user is currently signed into their facebook account. There HAS to be a cookie Groupon is reading. But how?

Comment: Essentially, when you do the Facebook login button, they (as in Facebook) read the Facebook cookies and then send a subset of that information down to you. Not sure how much in detail you're looking for in terms of an answer though. :)